# Anyway to contact moderator? I believe they closed my thread because of misunderstanding

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderation

I'm talking about this thread [Where to get boot image for Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/1560904/where-to-get-boot-image-for-windows)

I'm looking for boot image **FOR** Windows, not boot image **OF** Windows. The moderators closed the thread for "duplicate" and refer me to [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108085/where-can-i-get-a-clean-iso-of-a-specific-build-of-windows-10) Are "for Windows" and "of Windows" synonyms?

In my post I clearly stated I have Windows 10 ISO. Why do they refer my thread to one that is looking for Windows ISO? I already have it.

To make a DVD bootable, one need a boot image so it can be burned to the DVD and the resulting DVD will be bootable. That is the image I'm looking for, not the Windows 10 ISO image.

Comment: The tool listed in the duplicate topic should create a bootable media for you. If you have an iso image then the next step is simply burning it to a dvd. If you have the image then you have the bootable image and there is no different image. If you can change your question to state why that image is not bootable or what errors you get when trying to boot it then it might be able to be reopened.

Comment: I don't have an iso image to burn. I have files that I want to archive onto DVD's. At the same time, I want to make that DVD bootable. I used WinIso trying to make a bootable DVD but it asked me to locate the boot image. That's why I'm looking for a boot image, not the Windows 10 ISO, which I already have.

Comment: "I don't have an iso image to burn." and "the Windows 10 ISO, which I already have." are contradictory statements. You have an image, which is the image you need to burn, but for some unknown reason you believe it is not the image you need to burn. There is a disconnect between all the things you have and what you are trying to do with those things. Why do you believe that WinISO is required in order to create a bootable image from an already bootable image? It sounds, from your actual question, that you need to download the iso again, but select *only* 64-bit, not both 64 and 32.

Comment: Perhap I should have said I don't want to burn Windows 10 ISO. Why does everybody think I want to burn Windows 10 ISO? I want to archive files while making the DVD bootable.

Comment: Because we only know what you told us, that you have a windows image and somehow want to boot from the files on it. You never mentioned that what you want is a backup of some files together with a bootable Windows environment. That is the disconnect I (and others) have been trying to get you to explain.

Answer (score 5):

> In my post I clearly stated I have Windows 10 ISO. Why do they refer my thread to one that is looking for Windows ISO? I already have it.

You mention the fact you have a Windows 10 ISO but it's to large to write to a DVD.  I took this as an indication you were not aware of how to properly create a Windows 10 installation media.

> I'm looking for boot image FOR Windows, not boot image OF Windows.  Why does everybody think I want to burn Windows 10 ISO? I want to archive files while making the DVD bootable.

You indicated you were looking to create a bootable image.  You specifically talk about the Windows 10 ISO several times in your question. When I flagged your question as a duplicate, at the time, you had not submitted any comments under the only answer you received.  The answer you receive was nearly a duplicate of an answer to that of the duplicate question.

> 1. What I have is the Windows 10 ISO which is more than 5G and cannot fit on a single layer DVD.
> 2. I have Windows 10 1909 64 bit ISO whose size is 5,294,394 Kb, obviously too big for a single layer DVD.

Your current question does not indicate what bootable environment you are expecting to use.  So it's unclear if you are looking to use WinRE which makes the most sense, but isn't exactly the simplest to create, without any knowledge of how to create a custom WinRE image.

**You only later qualified what you were actually looking for, but even your clarification, is not all that detailed.**

> I want to archive files and, at the same time, make the DVD bootable.

In order to answer this question, we need to know what bootable environment you want to use, your question only mentions the Windows 10 installation media.

> I need a boot image to burn a bootable DVD for Windows 10.

> (Is there) anyplace to download a boot image or anyway to extract the boot image from an ISO file on hard disk?

This specific question is outside the scope of Super User.  How is anyone suppose to provide a bootable ISO if we know nothing about what you are trying to achieve.  **Your question in it's current revision makes no mention of the fact you want to backup up your files and have access to those files in a bootable environment.**

So while your question might not be a duplicate of [Where can I get a clean ISO of a specific build of Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/1560904/where-to-get-boot-image-for-windows), **it's currently not clear enough, to actually answer your question.**